# Player doesn't spawn correctly in procedural generated map

Tags: game-development, godot, procedural-generation, gdscript

I've followed "Procedural Generation in Godot: Dungeon Generation" by KidsCanCode @https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3fwlk1NI-w and find myself unable to debug the current problem.

[This specific commit](https://github.com/johnnybigoode/procedural_generation_godot/commit/70874aab0a49ba848e92101bd25fa67d276efad4) has the code, but I'll try to explain in more detail bellow.

My main scene has a Camera2D node, a generic Node2D calles Rooms and a TileMap, everything is empty.

When the script starts, it runs a

```
func make_room(_pos, _size):
    position = _pos
    size = _size
    
    var s = RectangleShape2D.new()
    s.custom_solver_bias = 0.5
    s.extents = size
    $CollisionShape2D.shape = s
```

A few times and it fills `$Rooms` using `.add_child(r)` where `r` is a instance of the node that has the `make_room()` function. It will then iterate over `$Rooms.get_children()` a few times to create a `AStar` node to link all the rooms:

[image: Map before carving into tilemap]

The magic comes when `make_map()` is called after afterwards, it fills the map with non-walkable blocks and then it carves the empty spaces, which works fine too:

[image: Map after carvinho into tilemap]

There is a `find_start_room()` that is called to find the initial room, it also sets a global variable to the Main script `start_room`, which is used to write 'Start' on the map using `draw_string(font, start_room.position - Vector2(125,0),"start",Color(3,4,8))`

When I hit 'esc' it runs this simple code to instance the player:

```
player = Player.instance()
add_child(player)
player.position = start_room.position + Vector2(start_room.size.x/2, start_room.size.y/2)
play_mode = true
```

[image: Player spawning on impossible terrain]

The problem comes when spawning the player. I tried doing some 'blind' fixing, such as adding or subtracting a `Vector2(start_room.size.x/2, start_room.size.y/2)` to player.position to see if I could make it fall within the room, to no avail.

Turning to the debugger didn't help, as the positions expressed by the variable inspectors don't seem to mean anything.

I tried implementing a simple 'mouse click print location':

```
    print("Mouse Click/Unclick at: ", event.position)
    print("Node thing",get_node("/root/Main/TileMap").world_to_map(event.position))
```

And also a 'start_room' print location:

```
print(get_node("/root/Main/TileMap").world_to_map(start_room.position))
```

And a when player moves print location, written directly into the Character script:

```
print(get_node("/root/Main/TileMap").world_to_map(self.position))
```

Getting results like the ones bellow:

```
Mouse Click/Unclick at: (518, 293)
Node thing(16, 9)
(-142, 0)
(-147, -3)
```

So, the player doesn't spawn on the same position as the start_room and the mouse position information is not the same as anything else.

Why is the player now spawning correctly? How can I debug this situation?

EDIT1: User Theraot mentioned about how the RigidBody2D is doing some weird collisions, and from what I understood, changing their collision behavior should fix the whole thing.

There's a section on the code that -after generating the random rooms- it removes some of the rooms like this:

```
for room in $Rooms.get_children():
    if randf() < cull:
        room.queue_free()
    else:
        room.mode = RigidBody2D.MODE_STATIC
        room_positions.append(Vector3(room.position.x, room.position.y, 0))
```

From what I understand, if the room is randomly selected it will be deleted using `queue_free()` OR it will be appended to a `room_positions` for further processing. This means if I shift all the rooms to a different collision layer, the player/character instance would be alone with the TileMap on the same collision layer.

So I just added a simple `room.collision_layer = 3` changing this section of the code to

```
for room in $Rooms.get_children():
    if randf() < cull:
        room.queue_free()
    else:
        room.mode = RigidBody2D.MODE_STATIC
        room.collision_layer = 3
        room_positions.append(Vector3(room.position.x, room.position.y, 0))
```

It doesn't seem to have changed anything, the player still spawns outside the room.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the rooms spread outwards?

You didn't write code to move the rooms. Sure, the code gives them a random position. But even if you set their position to `Vector2.ZERO` they move outwards, avoiding overlaps.

Why? Because these rooms are `RigidBody2D`, and they do push other physics objects. Such as other rooms or the player character.

---

That's the problem: These rooms are `RigidBody2D`, and you put your `KinematicBody2D` player character on top of one of them. The `RigidBody2D` pushes it out.

---

The tutorial you followed is exploiting this behavior of `RigidBody2D`s to spread the rooms. However you don't need these `RigidBody2D` after you are done populating your `TileMap`.

Instead, you can store the start position in a variable for later placing the player character (you don't need offsets - by the way - the position of the room is the center of the room), and then remove the `RigidBody2D`s. *If you want to keep the code that writes the text, you would also have to modify it, so it does not fail when the room no longer exists.*

Alternatively, you can edit their collision layer and mask so they don't collide with the player character (or anything for that matter, but why would you want these `RigidBody2D`s that collide with nothing?).

---

**Addendum post edit**: Collision layers and mask don't work as you expect.

First of all, the collision layer and mask are flags. The values of the layers are powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8...). So, when you set it to 3, it is the layer 1 plus the layer 2. So it still collides with a collision mask of 1.

And second, even if you changed the collision layer of the rooms to 2 (so it does not match the collision mask of 1 that the player character has). The player character still has a layer 1 which match the collision mask of the rooms.

*See also the proposal [Make physics layers and masks logic simple and consistent](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/2775).*

Thus, you would need to change the layer and mask. Both. in such way that they don't collide. For example, you can set layer and mask to 0 (which disable all collisions). *The algorithm that populates the `TileMap` does not use the layer and mask.*

Comment: That explains some of my doubts XD
After the map is created, there's a 'cull' section, I'll add to the original question to explain why the collision is not what is causing the wrongful spawn.